# How do I get and set checkedlistbox data whether its bound content of from the list itself

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Hello I am making a custom checkboxlist by inheriting a the winforms checkedlistbox directly. 
I was wondering how I would go about making setdata and getdata methods for it that return the binded data, checklistbox data, or null depending on which is valid first.

I currently have the bound data part but now I am stuck on getting the values from the checklistbox itself.

I need to mainly be able to get the text and checked property.

```
private object GetData(int index, string name)
{
    if (DataSource != null) return (DataSource as DataTable).Rows[index][name];
    else                    return Items[index]. //?? not sure what to do here Items is a ObjectCollection.
}

private void   SetData(int index, string name, object value)
{
    if (DataSource != null) return (DataSource as DataTable).Rows[index][name] = value;
    else                    return Items[index] //?? not sure what to do here Items is a ObjectCollection. = value
}
```

when I have these methods I will use it like this...

```
//TextEdit
private void CreateEditBox()
{
    editBox1Row = SelectedIndex;
    Rectangle r = GetItemRectangle(editBox1Row);

    editBox1.Location = new Point(21, 2 + (editBox1Row * 15));
    editBox1.Size     = new Size(r.Width, 13);
    editBox1.Show();
    editBox1.Focus();
    editBox1.Text = GetData(editBox1Row, "Name");
    editBox1.SelectAll();
    editBox1.KeyPress  += new KeyPressEventHandler(editBox1_EditOver);
    editBox1.LostFocus += new         EventHandler(editBox1_FocusOver);
}
```

I hope I wrote this clearly feel free to ask me any questions that I might have forgotten to cover.

Comment: The idiom most windows controls use rather than a `GetData` is to have a CheckedItems or CheckedIndicies collection.  Typically these are maintained as items are checked.  Also consider what happens when the DataSource is other than a DataTable.

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to say. what is the benefit of having a checkedItems or checkedIndices collection? I have a data class called layers which basically contains a `Enabled` property and a `Name` property in which the `Enabled` property cannot be bound to the the checkboxlists checkboxes